# Ajax load more and query in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I try to have a load more button for my posts. It works great except the third time when get the same three posts for example if I had posts t10 to t1 . I get t10 t9 t8 then when I click on load more I get t7 t6 t5 and the third time I get the same 3 posts and after that i always get these 3 posts. I think the problem come from offset but it seems ok to me

Comment: what about using "page" instead of "offset"

Comment: @S.Gholizadeh paged give the number of page and offset the number of posts to pass over. How could I replace one by another ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `paged` parameter instead of `offset`, `page` is mean for static front page.

> paged (int) - number of page. Show the posts that would normally show up just on page X when using the "Older Entries" link.
>
> posts_per_page (int) - number of post to show per page (available since Version 2.1, replaced showposts parameter). Use 'posts_per_page'=>-1 to show all posts (the 'offset' parameter is ignored with a -1 value). Set the 'paged' parameter if pagination is off after using this parameter.

[Codex : Pagination parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't understant how a parameter which show the number of page could give me the number of posts already display but I try this. I replace offset by $page = (isset($_POST['pageNumber'])) ? $_POST['pageNumber'] : 0; in function.php and I put var pageNumber = 3; in function.js with data: {
                'cat': cat,
                'ppp': ppp,
                'pageNumber': pageNumber,
                'action': 'more_post_ajax'
            }, but I get t10 t9 t8 t4 t3 t2 and then t4 t3 t2

Comment: from the codex example, it's better to do it like this : $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'paged' => $paged ) );

Comment: I do it with $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; but I get t10 t9 t8 t10 t9 t8 and so on

Comment: change page number (+1) after each click. do you have paged variable in query to use get_query_var('paged') ?

Comment: Ok It works. I understand how you replace offset by page parameter. I put pagenumber to 1 in function.js and I increment it in load_posts function then I get back page variable in function.php in order to use it in args query. Thanks to both of you Benoti and @S.Gholizadeh